# display data dynamically in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This form helps the user to enter few values to the database. I want to put a check that when a user enters a number, then all those addresses should get displayed that are present corresponding to that phone no. 
But this should happen before submit button.

```
<?
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        /*
        *
        *
        code to insert database
        *
        *
        */
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    /*
    *
    other inputs
    *
    */
    <input type="text" name="phoneno" value=""  />
    <button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Sample view of initial form will be

[image]

Sample view of form after entering phoneno

[image]

After entering all the values and selecting address then i would like to submit the form. Can anyone please tell me how to do so

Comment: Is this working for you yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery and ajax calls you can achieve your results like this.

The form...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phone").keyup(function() {  
        var number = $("#phone").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/processes/process-data.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'number='+number,
            cache: false,
    }).done(function( html ) { 
            $('#results').html(html);
        });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Phone #:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="results"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

process-data.php

```
<?php
require ('conn.php');

try {
    $val = $_POST['number'].'%';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM phones WHERE phonenumber LIKE :val";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':val', $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows = $stmt->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not update the table: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<?php do { ?>
<label><input type="radio" name="phoneno" value="<?php echo $row['phonenumber'] ?>"><?php echo $row['firstname'] ?> <?php echo $row['lastname'] ?> - <?php echo $row['phonenumber'] ?></label><br>
<?php } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
```

The DB I used to test above code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phones` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `phones` (`ID`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `phonenumber`) VALUES
(1, 'Name', '1', '9158591915'),
(2, 'Name', '2', '9158591916'),
(3, 'Name', '3', '9158591920'),
(4, 'Name', '4', '9158591836'),
(5, 'Name', '5', '9158592274'),
(6, 'Name', '6', '9158577188'),
(7, 'Name', '7', '9158572468'),
(8, 'Name', '8', '9158635700'),
(9, 'Name', '9', '9159517539'),
(10, 'Name', '10', '9168745291'),
(11, 'Name', '11', '9226543210');
```

Using the code above you will see that as you start typing "9" gives you all results... "91" drops to 10... "915" drops to 9... "9158" drops to 8... "91585" drops to 7 reults... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't code but share a process.

1. when user entered number then call a JavaScript event and call a AJAX for fetching related data {Addresses} in JSON format.
2. After getting JSON data you can put down all decoded JSON data after the numbers div.

Comment: i tried doing so but it required click of a submit button whereas i need without submit button

Comment: you can use onkeypress javascript Event Attribute 
e.g. <input type="text" onkeypress="get_addresses()">

Answer (score -2):

You can try jquery `autocomplete`. Details link here
[jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)